# How to disable visibility properties in animation (in viewport and render) for animated objects?

Tags: animation

As an example : we have a collection of 30 cubes animated, some in scale, some in position/rotation or both.
I would like to see them all disappear at a certain frame.

- I cannot join them (because of individual transformation keyframed).
- I cannot link the animation datas (because they are different except for visibility).
  Ultimately I thought I found a solution with geometry nodes with a ***Collection Info*** node that "clone" in one mesh the content of my cubes collection and so I can keyframe his visibility in the outliner. I have to exclude frome view layer the original cubes collection.
  But I am curious to know if there was a solution before the geonodes advent.

Thank you very much.

Comment: put them all in the same collection.  You can then animate the visibility properties of the collection as a whole.

Comment: @Marty Fouts Are you sure? How? You can keyframe a collection instance visibility though

Comment: @moonboots.  Oops.  I must have used an add-on that allows that.  You're right.  In 3.1, at least, you can't keyframe those.

Comment: From Marty and moonboots comments, there appears to be a lacking in capability.  I also tried using "Instance to Scene" (selecting the collection in the outliner and right-menu) and still couldn't find a way to animate render.    I would use a trick: add a Build modifier to a new object, select Reverse and set the Start Frame one prior to "disappearance", set Frame Count to '1'.  Select all other objects, then the new modified object last and use Object >> Link/Transfer >> Copy Modifiers.  This should then add the one modifier to all others.  Delete the new unneeded object.

Answer (score 1):

Before taking this advise, as an info I'm using Blender 2.92. First, select the object you want to apply this effect with. Then in Object Properties, scroll down to Visibility tab,and in there there's this 'Renders' check box. It has an Animate Property next to it. You can then animate this property as you wish. For example , if you want the objects to show up from frame 0 to 24, then disappear at frame 25, then do the following: 1) go to frame 0, check the box and click on the animate property, 2) go to frame 24, and re-click on the animate property, 3) go to the next frame, frame 25, and uncheck the box, then click on the animate property.

However, with this way, you need to do it one object at the time, because there's no Object Properties on Collections.